# List currently active websphere variables in server using wsadmin

Tags: websphere, environment-variables, wsadmin

how can I list using the **wsadmin** tool the currently active websphere variables and its values in a node/server ? Additionally, is there a way to filter the results using regular expressions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [`AdminTask.showVariables`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_atvariableconfig.html) command is a convenient method that allows you to retrieve WAS environment variables. These are returned as a string representation when obtaining a list of variables, though, so it's not as convenient for this purpose.

Alternatively, you can use the [`AdminConfig`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_adminconfig1.html). I'm not aware of any way to filter the results of these commands using regular expressions. The `AdminConfig.list` command allows filtering by regular expressions, but I haven't been able to get this to work with environment variables. My *guess* is that it filters based on the `name` attribute, but because the variable entry name is actually `symbolicName`, it doesn't work. You can still filter the results after retrieving all variables by applying some custom conditionals to test the `symbolicName`.

```
import re    
vars = AdminConfig.getid("/Node:%s/VariableMap:/VariableSubstitutionEntry:/" % node).splitlines()
for var in vars :
    name = AdminConfig.showAttribute(var, "symbolicName")
    if ( re.match("yourRegularExpression", name) ) :
        value = AdminConfig.showAttribute(var, "value")
        print "%s = %s" % (name, value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want One-liner Jacl to print the value pairs ...

```
wsadmin>

foreach x [$AdminConfig getid /Node:/VariableMap:/VariableSubstitutionEntry:/] { puts [$AdminConfig showAttribut
e $x "symbolicName"] ; puts [$AdminConfig showAttribute $x "value"] ;   }
```